# Getting pixel data from an image using java

Tags: java, rgb

I'm trying to get the pixel rgb values from a `64 x 48` bit image. I get some values but nowhere near the `3072 (= 64 x 48)` values that I'm expecting. I also get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:301)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:871)
at imagetesting.Main.getPixelData(Main.java:45)
at imagetesting.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

I can't find the out of bounds error...

Here's the code:

```
package imagetesting;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



public class Main {

public static final String IMG = "matty.jpg";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedImage img;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(IMG));

        int[][] pixelData = new int[img.getHeight() * img.getWidth()][3];
        int[] rgb;

        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < img.getHeight(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++){
                rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);

                for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++){
                    pixelData[counter][k] = rgb[k];
                }

                counter++;
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);

int rgb[] = new int[] {
    (argb >> 16) & 0xff, //red
    (argb >>  8) & 0xff, //green
    (argb      ) & 0xff  //blue
};

System.out.println("rgb: " + rgb[0] + " " + rgb[1] + " " + rgb[2]);
return rgb;
}

}
```

Comment: Why not put a catch in your main to get the exception and print out the loop indexes that the problem happened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
for(int i = 0; i < img.getHeight(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++){
        rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);
```

Does not match up with this:

```
private static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
```

You have `i` counting the rows and `j` the columns, i.e. `i` contains *y* values and `j` contains *x* values. That's backwards.

Comment: I would rename your variables to x and y personally.

Comment: I would name them "row" and "column" to be even more precise. The y-axis is most often inverted (top->down) which is different from what we are used to with a xy-coordinate system. With row and column it ieasier to think of the image as a matrix and then the indices are not ambigous.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for this same ability. Didn't want to enumerate the entire image, so I did some searching and used PixelGrabber.

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filename);
PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);

pg.grabPixels(); // Throws InterruptedException

width = pg.getWidth();
height = pg.getHeight();

int[] pixels = (int[])pg.getPixels();
```

You could use the `int[]` directly here, pixels are in a format dictated by the ColorModel from `pg.getColorModel()`, or you can change that false to true and force it to be RGB8-in-ints.

I've since discovered that the `Raster` and Image classes can do this too, and there have been some useful classes added in `javax.imageio.*`.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename)); // Throws IOException
int[] pixels = img.getRGB(0,0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight, null, 0, img.getWidth());

// also available through the BufferedImage's Raster, in multiple formats.
Raster r = img.getData();
int[] pixels = r.getPixels(0,0,r.getWidth(), r.getHeight(), (int[])null);
```

There are several `getPixels(...)` methods in `Raster` as well.

Comment: +1 I think the last call to has a missing `null` parameter at the end: `int[] pixels = r.getPixels(0, 0, r.getWidth(), r.getHeight(), (int[])null);`

Answer (score 5):

This works too:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);

int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Comment: What should the type of the variable `file` be in this case?

Comment: this gives class cast exception for me - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferInt

Comment: You cannot blindly cast the databuffer to a DataBufferInt, the concrete type depends on the original type (and the particular decoder decision).

Answer (score 3):

`int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);`  Your code

`int argb = img.getRGB(y, x);`  my changes now it works

Answer (score 2):

You have to change:

```
for(int i = 0; i < img.getHeight(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++){
        rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);
```

Into

```
for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++){
        rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);
```

Because the second parameter from `getPixelData` is the `x`-value and the thirth is the `y`-value. You switched the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't use just use:

```
public int[] getRGB(int startX,
                    int startY,
                    int w,
                    int h,
                    int[] rgbArray,
                    int offset,
                    int scansize)
```

It's built-in, man.