# Grab x,y coordinates for a given pixel RGB?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a screenshot method in my code and a `BufferedImage` instance. I'm wondering if it's possible to search the image data for a specific RGB, then return the X,Y coordinates for the pixel.

What could I use for that?  Is it possible at all?

Comment: You want the position of the first pixel with the given RGB, if I get it right?

Comment: checkt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604319/getting-pixel-data-from-an-image-using-java) question out

Comment: It depends on how you store the image. Eg if you have it as a 2D array you can just look through it collecting the matching pixels indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int[] searchForColor(BufferedImage bi, int searchColor)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); ++x)
    for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); ++y)
    {
        if ((bi.getRGB(x, y) & 0x00FFFFFF) == searchColor)
            return new int[]{x, y};
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
BufferedImage bi = takeScreenShot();
int searchColor = 0x2D5E83; // A random color
int[] coordinate = searchForColor(bi, searchColor);
int x = coordinate[0];
int y = coordinate[1];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch, I've been at school & work the whole day so I'll try it out tomorrow. It looks like the kind of code I'm looking for, again, thanks a bunch for the headsup!

Comment: What if the RGB is retrieved from three SeekBars. What part of the code would change?

Comment: @SiKni8: Combine them together. Suppose you have `int r, g, b`, each between 0 and 255 (inclusive), then do: `int rgb = (b << 16) | (b << 8) | (r);`.

Comment: So, the variable searchColor would be replaced with rgb?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Just pass your `rgb` to the method as second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-color-of-pixel.shtml and loop thru the image data