# Java Robot class mouse move to position of a specific pixel (Mouse click a color)

Tags: java, colors, click, position, awtrobot

How to find the position of a color that is changing coordinates and needs to be click after being identified.

Purpose of the program complete tasks in a game, requiring the clicking of different colors which aren't always in the same position.

Code currently gets color of mouse's coordinates after 5 seconds of executing program

---

```
public class RobotColorClick 
{

    public RobotColorClick () throws AWTException, IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        //Delay 5 seconds
        robot.delay(5000);        

        //Gets color (value of red,green,blue) from the mouse position after 5 seconds 
        Color color = robot.getPixelColor( MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x 
                , MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);

        //Delay 3 seconds
        robot.delay(3000);

        //Mouse moves to X and Y then right click
        //Problem! How to set X and Y to position color coordinates, position will change
        robot.mouseMove(x, y);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException, 
                InterruptedException 
    {
        new RobotColorClick ();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Advanced System Activities](http://sourceforge.net/p/javaxsystem/wiki/Home/#dcf7) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to take a screen shot image then spiral out (assuming the "color" is taking a continuous path and not jumping around) from the original location comparing the color of that pixel with the color you are looking for. Once that has been identified, do `mouseMove(newX, newY)` and then the `mousePress()`/`mouseRelease()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

if the color is taking continues path and not jumping around  [read Kevin Mangold answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15687454/11627616) otherwise if it is just a color appearing anywhere you I think you have 2 options(in case of the background being constant color):

**The First one:**  you can take screen shot iterate over it and get coordinates of any appearing color (or a specific color)then press on it using Robot lib,[this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995495/grab-x-y-coordinates-for-a-given-pixel-rgb) [and this for taking screenshots](http://www.javatechblog.com/java/how-to-take-screenshot-programmatically-in-java/)

**The second one:** if you don't want to take screenshots you can use the robot lib to iterate over your screen with a 2 nested for loops iterating over all screen pixels [THis may help](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-robot-class-get-pixel-color-given-point/)

***In case of*** background image is not constant you can take screenshot of the screen and compare it with the previous one ,use robot lib to press on the difference.

**Extra** I have read somewhere before that when pressing on a button using robot lib ,it is better to do this
`robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.delay(1); 
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);`
instead of this

```
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

**Extra thing** you can read the game memory from you software and get the color coordinates you want