# How to convert JPG data stored in a Byte array to BGR data in java

Tags: java, image, jpeg, bmp, javax.imageio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting pixel data from an image using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604319/getting-pixel-data-from-an-image-using-java)

I was already browsing the web for quite some time, but didn't find any suitable answer, so I would be very happy if someone here could help me :)

I have a Byte array which is filled with image data  encoded as JPEG. Now I would like to know how to convert the data to the corresponding BGR data of the image and store it in a byte array as well.

Thank you very much in advance, your help is really appreciated!

Comment: *"I was already browsing the web for quite some time"*  What were the search terms used?  What were the top 3 hits?  Why were those hits unsuitable?

Comment: Blue, Green, Red.  The more common way of naming color data is RGB.

Comment: Nice, would be fair to let me reply before downrating my question.. 
Search terms used, in different combinations: Java, Convert, JPEG, Bmp, Bitmap, JPG, Library, BufferedImage, ImageIO. 
Top hits mostly referred either using ImageIO which seems(!) not to work on a Bytearray (however I would be happy to learn it is) or are working on a file to file base which is not applicable for me as I need to do some time-crucial processing after

@Le Blanc: RGB is more common, but BGR is actually the "encoding" of images in BMP etc. That is why I kept my question to BGR

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Saw that already. Maybe I made myself unclear in my question that I am forced on a array to array basis. The link you provided uses ImageIO to read an Image-file, I already have my Jpeg Data in a byte array

Comment: @Blahnik: Then your question should be, how do I convert JPG to BMP?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: I don't understand your comment (and the second downrate, probably thanks to you).
1. the additional .._stored in byte array_ was to emphasize what obviusly was already ignored, that the data is in an array
2. Actually I really would prefer having the "raw" BGR data instead of a bmp with its header. Conversion to BMP is a undesirable intermediate step  -->no need for a downrate im(h)o

Comment: now, can anyone tell me why me questions gets downrated? It is not imho that there has already been a duplicate question and also, my comments had their justification due to the previous comments.. thanks

Comment: @Blahnik - your question got down-voted because it was considered to be of poor quality. Generally that means that the other members of the site considered it to be too broad with not enough factual information to warrant time spent on answering it. The more time you put in providing **useful** details about your problem the better help you'll get!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I actually tried to consider this. Imho all the necessary info was given. Maybe I should had emphasize that my Image data was stored in a byte array and not in a file, what all the other posts, like the suggested duplicate post, are dealing with. Hope my post helps some other people whose data is already in an array and not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input); 
    ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", output);  
    byte[] outputBytes = output.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out when I am back in the office.

Still would be thankful for any solution without the "intermediate steps" especially because no it is a Bitmap I have to add some additional steps to get rid of the bmp header and info part.

Comment: @Blahnik: You should be able to extract the data directly from the BufferedImage ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8631366/)), but you may need to convert it to the type you want (TYPE_INT_BGR or TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) if it doesn't have the right type already (e.g. by creating a new BufferedImage of the same size with the desired type and calling .getGraphics().drawImage() on it).

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Thank you, that basically works. Also the Link Ilmari gave was quite useful to get the RGB data. 

The only thing which I am still not very happy about is that the necessary time for the conversion is quite high. It takes approx 80 ms for the bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(inputStream) line and another 100 ms for the bufferedImage.getRGB(0,0,width, height, Array, width) line. I am using a Dual Core 3 Ghz and 4 GB Ram and am processing a 2 MP image. Is there any way to improve the speed? Thanks!

Comment: @Blahnik: You don't say how large your images are, but those speeds seem reasonable for the amount of work that has to be done to process images.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for your reply. The size of the 2-MP BMP is due to its 24 bit BGR encoding around 6,3 MB. But true, didn't say anything about the JPEG which is around 140 KB. Do you or anyone else has experiences with libraries, which we so far wanted to avoid, and can tell me whether there would be an improvement? E.g.  libjpegturbo? Thanks!