# How to make pixel be in range [1-255] in java in matrix form (x-y plane)?

Tags: java, png, pixel

I have an image of (512 pixels * 512 pixels) of type PNG. I knew that each pixel is of type 8 bits. So, we have range [0-255]. the question is I want the row and column of this image such that the each cell has a number in between [0-255].

Unfortunately, my program works fine without error, but the bad news is that it doesn't come with what I want. the output for each cell there is 7 numbers i.e. 2894893 -2829100 -2829100 -2894893 -2894893 -2960686 -2960686 -2960686 -3092272 -3223858 -3289651 -3421237 -4144960 -3684409 -3552823 -4144960 -4802890 -5263441 etc.

what I want is only a range between [1-255]?
i.e. instead of the above output, we should have something like 
23 182 33 250 etc.

remember that I need this using 2-dimensional instead of 1-dimensional (means array[row] [column] instead of array [index]).
Here is the code:

```
 ima = ImageIO.read(new File("how.png"));

    int [] pix = ima.getRGB(0, 0, ima.getWidth(), ima.getHeight(), null, 0, ima.getWidth());

    int count=0;        
    for (int i=0; i < ima.getHeight() ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < ima.getWidth() ; j++){
            System.out.print(pix[count]+" ");
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

This method is taken from the member @davenpcj from [getting pixel data from an image using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604319/getting-pixel-data-from-an-image-using-java).

Thank you

Comment: "I knew that each pixel is of type 8 bits" What does that mean? 8 bits per channel? how many channels? grayscale? indexed (palette)? Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting are RGB values, where each of the three components is stored as a byte.  That is, the integer consists of 4 bytes, each one for the R, G, B and alpha components of the pixel. For example, the pixel value 2894893 looks like this as binary:

```
 00000000 00101100 00101100 00101101
```

You can get the individual channels by masking the integer pixel value:

```
int red = (pix[count] & 0xFF);
int green = (pix[count] >> 8) & 0xFF;    
int blue = (pix[count] >> 16) & 0xFF;
int alpha = (pix[count] >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I think this way it doesn't work for me, I have a question, Suppose that I need to get the data of image into a matrix of integer, and the image is on the grayscale (means white and black) then does "red", "green", "blue", and "alpha" make a difference? or in other words, if I have grayscale image, then does getRGP() is the only way to get the data from the image to be in the form of integer 2-dimensional?

Comment: If it is grayscale, then all you'll need is red, since all three RGB components will be the same.  Also note, I updated my answer -- now all components will be in the range of 0-255.  How many dimensions your array is doesn't matter.  Just create a two-dimensional array if that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much again, Is this the same as if you take the average value of Red, Green, and Blue (I found this page here http://www.dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-convert-a-color-image-into-grayscale-image-in-java) or this is different? Thank you for your nice answer ..